# Not able to change the action (parameter) attribute in form tag (method get), in Spring MVC 4.3.9

Tags: javascript, spring, forms, model-view-controller, action

I want to share some SpringMVC form action unchangeable issue solutions, that I could not find on the internet including here. (might be duplicate)
But I'm almost a freshman in StackOverflow, so I'm just here to ask myself and answer myself right away.
// I have tried to share the solution public on GitHub issue, I could not use it well, too.
// asking to be excused...

---

I found something like a bug, in Spring MVC 4.3.9.
When I try to change the action attribute of the form tag (method get) in a javascript function,
the URL mapping in the address window of the web browser (I'm using Firefox)
is always typed as the action +  the name of the input tag inside the form tag.

```
<form action="mappingInControllerToSend" method="get" id="theForm">
  <input type="text" name="test1"/>
</form>
<button onclick="formActionChange()"/>
<!-- blah blah -->
<script>
  function formActionChange(){
   var theForm = document.getElementById("theForm");
   var newParam = "test2";
   theForm.action = "mappingInControllerToSend?" + newParam;
  }
</script>

<!-- the default value of the 'method' attribute in form tag is "get",
so if you don't write the method attribute at all,
then you are using get method, so getting this same wrong result. -->
```

In this case, by the book, I should connect to "mappingInControllerToSend?test2" in Controller
(with the parameter, test2).

But I always connect to "mappingInControllerToSend?test1" in Controller
(with the parameter, test1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Solution **
=> You should change the method of the form tag, form "get" to "post"
=> When the method is "post", now it goes to "mappingInControllerToSend?test1" in Controller, as coded.

// P.S.
-- I'm not sure if it is a bug. (I am sorry if it is a planned feature in Spring MVC.)
-- But I at least hope this might be helpful to people who are stuck in the same problem.